# Exception: The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use an OCR tool. This tool gets text from PDF and converts it to RTF.

Then I have to convert it to HTML, so I use:

```
outputText = MarkupConverter.RtfToHtmlConverter.ConvertRtfToHtml(
                System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(response.fileData));
```

I put a break point in this line, cause after this row, I got an exception of:

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

So I tried to put `<STAThread()>` above the function:

```
<STAThread()>
Public Shared Function GetFileTextByOCRTool(path As String) As String
```

But it doesn't work (I get the same exception)..

Doesn't it (`<STAThread()>`) define the function as STA?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the [`STAThreadAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation you will see the following remark:

> Apply this attribute to the entry point method (the `Main()` method in C# and Visual Basic). It has no effect on other methods. To set the apartment state of threads you start in your code, use the `Thread.SetApartmentState` or `Thread.TrySetApartmentState` method before starting the thread.

So you have to mark you application entry point using the attribute (otherwise your main thread will enter the MTA), or if you are calling the component from another thread you need to call [`Thread.SetApartmentState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the thread to STA before the thread is started.

Note that once a thread uses COM interop and enters an apartment it is not possible for the thread to leave the apartment and enter another one.

If you are using task or thread pool threads you will not be able to set the apartment state to STA.